# Flutter: Custom Scroll view for top layer in multi layer stack

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-sliver

is there a flutter widget to build to scroll like the way we see in Google Maps where top layer (i.e. list of cards) is scrolling over the bottom layer (i.e. map). And when the top layer is not obscuring bottom layer, bottom layer is also "intreactable" the way map is. something like this https://gfycat.com/pastelgenerousgoosefish (at 10:30 secs mark).

if there is no widget available, how would i go about achieving scroll effect like this?

I have been trying to use slivers but it doesn't allow me to create effect like this or i haven't been able to find it yet.

Answer (score 0):

You can put a `listview` inside a `SizedBox` this way:

```
 ClipRRect(
            borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(40.0),
            child: SizedBox(
              height: 85,
              child: ListView.builder(
                  physics: ClampingScrollPhysics(),
                  scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                  itemCount: 20,
                  itemBuilder: (BuildContext content, int index) {
                    double edgeSize = 0.0;
                    double itemSize = 80;
                    child: Text('List Item'),
                    }
                  )
                )
              )
```

Comment: Thanks @Mazin. However, i was able to solve the problem by using gesture detector and listening to onVerticalDrag update and moving widget position based on that information....something like this                                                                                                  child: GestureDetector(
            onVerticalDragUpdate: (listen) {
              _moveDelta = listen.primaryDelta;
              setState(() {
                }
              });
            }, child: Container()